# GettingAltitude (Heading) in Veins simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using Veins 4.4 with Omnet 4.6 and Sumo 0.25.

I would like to get information about the altitude of the vehicles. 
I just found the method getLonLat() in TraCICommandInterface class. 
Is there a method regarding the altitude or some other way to get this kind of information? Thanks

I tried to modify the mentioned function as follows:

```
std::list<double> TraCICommandInterface::getLonLatAlt(const Coord& coord) {
    TraCIBuffer request;
    request << static_cast<uint8_t>(POSITION_CONVERSION) << std::string("sim0")
            << static_cast<uint8_t>(TYPE_COMPOUND) << static_cast<int32_t>(2)
            << connection.omnet2traci(coord)
            << static_cast<uint8_t>(TYPE_UBYTE) << static_cast<uint8_t>(POSITION_LON_LAT_ALT);
    TraCIBuffer response = connection.query(CMD_GET_SIM_VARIABLE, request);


    uint8_t cmdLength; response >> cmdLength;
    if (cmdLength == 0) {
        uint32_t cmdLengthX;
        response >> cmdLengthX;
    }
    uint8_t responseId; response >> responseId;
    ASSERT(responseId == RESPONSE_GET_SIM_VARIABLE);
    uint8_t variable; response >> variable;
    ASSERT(variable == POSITION_CONVERSION);
    std::string id; response >> id;
    uint8_t convPosType; response >> convPosType;
    ASSERT(convPosType == POSITION_LON_LAT_ALT);
    double convPosLon; response >> convPosLon;
    double convPosLat; response >> convPosLat;
    double convPosAlt; response >> convPosAlt;

    std::list<double> geo_coordinates;
    std::list<double>::iterator it;

    geo_coordinates.insert(it,0,convPosLon);
    geo_coordinates.insert(it,1,convPosLat);
    geo_coordinates.insert(it,2,convPosAlt);

    return geo_coordinates;
}
```

but running in debug mode, it returns this error:

**Thread 1 "opp_run" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5ea5543 in std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
Python Exception  Cannot find type std::__cxx11::list >::const_iterator::_Node: 
Python Exception  Cannot find type std::__cxx11::list >::const_iterator::_Node: 
Python Exception  Cannot find type std::__cxx11::list >::const_iterator::_Node:**

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "heading". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I edited the post, it was ambiguous. I mean the altitude of the vehicle position. Actually I also need the heading of the vehicle which is a field of the basic safety message exchanged by cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modification is semantically sound, but syntactically wrong.

You are using `std::list::insert` incorrectly. The form you use takes an insert position (here, your code seems to supply an uninitialized iterator), a repetition count (here your code seems to supply what seems to be a position offset), and a value to insert.

Changing the `insert` statements to three statements using `push_back` yields working code (though note that the demo simulation yields missing values as no position mapping and no altitude values are defined).

Comment: @ChristopSommer you mean they are not defined in my code or in general in Veins? thanks to your suggestion I solved the syntatix error, but I actually get zero as altitude value which is not rea

Comment: The demo map that comes with Veins does not include elevation data. If you create your own map for SUMO, see the instructions on http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/Elevation